# How do I convert the following weekly Date format in SQL: (e.g. 2015-W34)

Tags: python, sql, db2, jupyter-lab

I've downloaded a dataset from the ECDC which has weekly entries in the following date format: "2015-W34". I have the file in an SQL database and am trying to convert the date to any regular date format eg yyyy/mm/dd.

The year starts at W01 and ends at W52 or W53. e.g The year 2017 ranges from: 2017-W01 to 2017-W52.

Any help is appreciated!

I'm using IBM Db2 in the cloud and accessing it via Jupyter labs, writing in Python 3.

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Which sql database  do you use: MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres ... ?

Comment: I'm using IBM Db2 in the cloud

Comment: Please define what the beginning of the year is.  It is not clear or (necessarily) formally defined.

Comment: The year starts for example "2017-W01". I've updated the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is in ISO format.  You can get the ISO year beginning using logic like this:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date) - 7 * (week_iso(current_date) - 1) day
```

You can apply this to your expression:

```
date_trunc('week', date(left(yyyyww, 4) || '02-01')) - 7 * (week_iso(date(left(yyyyww, 4) || '02-01')) - 1) day
```

Then you can add back the weeks:

```
date_trunc('week', date(left(yyyyww, 4) || '02-01')) - 7 * (week_iso(date(left(yyyyww, 4) || '02-01')) - 1) day + (cast(right(yyyyww, 2) as int) - 1) * 7 day
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following statement and its result:

```
WITH T(N, DT) AS 
(
VALUES (1, DATE('2014-12-29'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT N + 1, DT + 1
FROM T
WHERE N < 8
)
SELECT DT, WEEK_ISO(DT) WEEK_ISO, WEEK(DT) WEEK, DAYNAME(DT) DAYNAME FROM T;
```

The result is:

```
|DT        |WEEK_ISO   |WEEK       |DAYNAME   |
|----------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|2014-12-29|1          |53         |Monday    |
|2014-12-30|1          |53         |Tuesday   |
|2014-12-31|1          |53         |Wednesday |
|2015-01-01|1          |1          |Thursday  |
|2015-01-02|1          |1          |Friday    |
|2015-01-03|1          |1          |Saturday  |
|2015-01-04|1          |2          |Sunday    |
|2015-01-05|2          |2          |Monday    |
```

This is a demonstration of the fact, that relation between YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-W format is not `1:1`, but `N:1`.
This means that there is a number of dates which corresponds to the `2015-W01` format, and it depends on `W` meaning.
[WEEK](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000871.html)
[WEEK_ISO](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005481.html)

So, it's not possible to map a `YYYY-W` date (which is actually not a date, but a week reference) to `YYYY-MM-DD` **uniquely**. You must provide an exact formal description about exact date such a mapping must be done to.

## For example, such a description could be as follows

We map such a week `YYYY-WXX` to the date which we get as `YYYY-01-01` + (`XX-1`) weeks.
The implementation of this algorithm:

```
WITH PARMS (STR) AS 
(
VALUES
  '2015-W34'
, '2017-W01'
, '2017-W52'
)
SELECT 
  STR
, DATE(SUBSTR(STR, 1, 4) || '-01-01') + (INT(SUBSTR(STR, 7)) - 1) * 7 DT
FROM PARMS;
```

The result is:

```
|STR     |DT        |
|--------|----------|
|2015-W34|2015-08-20|
|2017-W01|2017-01-01|
|2017-W52|2017-12-24|
```

Comment: Not an answer to actual problem?  I agree with what you're pointing out here (although I agree with Gordon that it's likely the ISO week numbers), but shouldn't this normally be part of a comment for clarification?

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your time and advice there. Am reading through the documentation now.

Comment: The answer was, that it's impossible to do, what OP wants with the explanation. I've edited my answer with some guessing on how it may be possible to achieve the goal.